# Android studio and multiple button

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a **problem** **"@Topic"**

It is my **code:**

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button one = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    one.setOnClickListener(this); // calling onClick() method
    Button two = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    two.setOnClickListener(this);
    Button three = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
    three.setOnClickListener(this);
    Button four = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    four.setOnClickListener(this);
}

    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.button3:
                Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break;

            case R.id.button4:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewTwo.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;

            case R.id.button5:
                Intent intent_two = new Intent(this, NewThree.class);
                startActivity(intent_two);
                break;

            case R.id.button1:
                Intent intent_three = new Intent(this, NewFour.class);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Praca w toku...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                startActivity(intent_three);
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

    }
```

And it is log error:

> 08-04 12:35:08.852 596-596/com.example.tomecki.alarmclock E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                               Process: com.example.tomecki.alarmclock, PID: 596
>                                                                               android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.tomecki.alarmclock/com.example.tomecki.alarmclock.NewTimer}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
>                                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1777)
>                                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1501)
>                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3843)
>                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3797)
>                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4114)
>                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4082)
>                                                                                   at com.example.tomecki.alarmclock.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:41)
>                                                                                   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4793)
>                                                                                   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19971)
>                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5669)
>                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
>                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)

Line 41 it is:

```
 case R.id.button4:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewTimer.class);
 ---------->>>  startActivity(intent);
                break;
```

Please help me ;)

Comment: "have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?"

Answer (score 0):

It says in your log: have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml

Go to your AndroidManifest.xml and add your activities under the application tag like this:

```
<activity
        android:name=".NewTimer" />
```